# Unable to add framework (MessageUI) to target

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, frameworks

Obvious question if you know what/where to look...unfortunately I don't...yet.

When I double-click my target and try to add the MessageUI framework it's not listed. *I tried to do it manually and ran into trouble.* I see that this app's target is for 2.2.1 and obviously MessageUI requires 3.0. Where can I set this? Do I need to create a new target? **What doc should I read to understand this better?**

I haven't had much need to separate the various OS's...until now.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click the Project, go to General, and set the "Base SDK for all configurations."

Comment: Thanks. fyi- I found it under "Build" not "General"

Comment: Under General is a master switch (near the bottom of the pane). Under build, you need to make sure you're setting it correctly for all configurations.